# Openpyxl-read formulas results (Python 2.7)

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to read from an excel file. I am trying to read a cell whose value is calculated by a formula.

Regular reading functions returns formula script:

```
`wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('forecast.xlsx')`
`sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet3')`
`result=sheet["F6"].value`
```

I tried to use (data_only=True) flag like this:

`wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('forecast.xlsx', data_only=True)`

Result was that all formula cells turned to blanks. Only pure values remained.

Is there a way to read a cell calculated value using openpyxl?

**Update:**

From further reading I suspect the issue is about re-opening a file that was already modified with openpyxl. Once I open an original file, I get the values using `'data_only'` flag. Once re-opening after some modification, formula cells turn to blanks.

Tried solving this by working with 2 files- so far without much success.

Anybody has a solution for this?

Comment: Solution to what? You can either have the calculated values **or** the formulae. If you do you data-only mode don't overwrite the original file.

Answer (score 1):

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('forecast.xlsx', data_only=True)
```

Will read the actual value. (From what you have posted, I think you miss a comma that separates the arguments)

Comment: The comma is in the acutal code (Edited post as well). From further reading I suspect the issue is about re-opening a file that was already modified with openpyxl.  Once I open an orignal file, I get the values. Once re-opening, formula cells turn to blanks.