# Openpyxl format cell values as string

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a column whose values are in percent format and the value is defined using a formula written in some other columns. I want to get its value as 80% (for example). I am checking to data type but I am not able to convert the value to a string). Does anybody know any solution for that?

```
table = []
for row in act_sheet.iter_rows():
    if row[col].data_type == 'f':
        table.append(unicode(row[col].value))
print table
```

gives me something like:

```
[u'=O2/N2', u'=O3/N3', u'=O4/N4', u'=O5/N5', u'=', u'=', u'=', u'=', u'=O10/N10', u'=', u'=', u'=', u'=', u'=', u'=', u'=', u'=']
```

But these values are percentages like 80% in the table.
I am using Python 2.7 with Openpyxl 2.2.4

Comment: Can you try `.value2` or `.text` instead of `.value`? And why do you need the `unicode()`? Can you try without it?

Comment: Can you be more clear? You want to take the values from your column and do 80% of that? What do you mean "checking to datatype"? 
Can you make an example of a row and tell the operations you want to perform?

Comment: You should try editing the code for an indention error instead of adding an error as an answer, this is not helping to me or anybody reading this post. Please try to understand the problem, not try to find an error in the code. 80% is one of my cell value. I just basically convert the cell values to string before getting them to my table.

Comment: @vityata, I tried .value2 or .text but they are not working. I used unicode to get the values as string as suggested in another post but still it doesn't help to convert the percentage values to string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openpyxl-read formulas results (Python 2.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478237/openpyxl-read-formulas-results-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0):

One error is that you did not intended after the `if`:

```
if row[col].data_type == 'f':
    table.append(unicode(row[col].value))
```

For the rest please clarify your question: make an example with input rows and cells and the calculation you want to perform.