# How to get only the output of a formula with excel openpyxl python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

My code is:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dad_app\\template\\template.xlsm')
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
sheet = wb.active
sheet['A1:AP701'] = sheet['A1:AP701'].internal_value
```

But it saves the formula too.
How do I remove the formula and only get the output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openpyxl-read formulas results (Python 2.7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478237/openpyxl-read-formulas-results-python-2-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `data_only=True` as a parameter in `load_workbook`. It will return the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet.

Documentation: [Here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.6/api/openpyxl.reader.excel.html?highlight=data-only)

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dad_app\\template\\template.xlsm', data_only=True)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the authors problem, it would be nice to have some explaining words or documentation altogether with your code. Please edit your answer in that respect.

Comment: Edited as suggested